# Iterate through AndroidManifest.xml file of all installed applications?

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I iterate through `AndroidManifest.xml` file of all installed android application, in order to search for a specific tag/attribute?

```
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo application : applications) {        
    Log.d("", application.toString());
}
```

At the moment I manage to list only the installed apps. Couldn't find anything to reveal the manifest file for an `ApplicationInfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, consider using `PackageInfo` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) instead of `ApplicationInfo`. Most useful information in manifests can be accessed with simple method calls.

If you really want to parse XMLs, which are compiled as binary XMLs, here's a sample code.
https://github.com/yaraki/ManifestAnalyzer